# Getting Target Null Error message in Kotlin using Picasso

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, picasso

I am trying to display image using Json API but I am getting Target not null error message. I have three classes one main, adapter and model class. I have already added picasso library and the name is working fine without issue and image is an issue.  Any help is appreciated.

Main Class:

```
var Test:String=catObj.getString("Test")
category.Test=Test
Picasso.get().load(category.Test).into(TestImage)---TestImage is my ImageView ID.
```

Adapter class:

```
class ViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bindItem(Test:TestModel)
    {
        var name:TextView=itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.CatName)
        var picture:TextView=itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.CatImage)
        name.text=Test.name
        picture.text=Test.location

    }
}
```

Error Log:

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
```

Comment: share your error log @Joshva Jo

Comment: Target not null error message???
do you mean target is null?? share the log and the line where you got the exception.
and use TestImage!! to confirm that target is not null.

Comment: you have to set image like this Picasso.with(context).load(item).into(yourtarget)

Comment: @unzila I am using kotlin so, I am using Picasso.get().load(category.Test).into(TestImage)

Comment: in kotlin picasso implementation is same like java , i used it many times

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Every one for their response. I solved it via below changes in my code.

Main Class:

```
var Test:String=catObj.getString("Test")
category.Test=Test
```

Adapter Class:

```
class ViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bindItem(Test:TestModel)
    {
        var name:TextView=itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.CatName)
        var picture:ImageView=itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.CatImage)
        name.text=Test.name
        Picasso.get().load(category.picture).into(location)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this in kotlin its working

```
 Picasso.get().load(category.picture).into(object : com.squareup.picasso.Target {
            override fun onBitmapFailed(e: Exception?, errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
                TODO("not implemented") 
            }

            override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap?, from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?) {
                // loaded bitmap is here (bitmap)

                holder.binding.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            }

            override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) {}
            
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @unzila for your response. My below response worked for me.